# printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK in C# was working, now it's stopped working

Tags: c#

In my program I have the following code fragment:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        string strText = "";
        foreach (object x in listBox1.Items)
        {
            strText = strText + x.ToString() + "\n";
        }

        myReader = new StringReader(strText);

        try
        {
            if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.printDocument1.Print();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This worked to print everything inside listBox1.

As part of an update, I changed an SQL server reference at another part of the code, and now this section returns "External component has thrown an error".

I have absolutely no idea where to go from here, as even changing the reference back still throws the exception. I even tried running a previous build which worked earlier this morning, but now I get the exception.

Full exception details:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=External component has thrown an exception.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.PrintDlgEx(PRINTDLGEX lppdex)
       at System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog.ShowPrintDialog(IntPtr hwndOwner, PRINTDLGEX data)
       at System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog.RunDialog(IntPtr hwndOwner)
       at System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
       at System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog()
       at McBeathTraining.GapCheck.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Benjamin.Roffey\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\McBeathTraining\McBeathTraining\GapCheck.cs:line 191
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
       at McBeathTraining.Form1.GapCheck_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Benjamin.Roffey\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\McBeathTraining\McBeathTraining\Form1.cs:line 96
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at McBeathTraining.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Benjamin.Roffey\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\McBeathTraining\McBeathTraining\Program.cs:line 17
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: I have one suggestion: Temporarily replace the erratic section of code with `using (var printDialog = new PrintDialog() { printDialog.ShowDialog(); }`. If even that fails, then something is seriously wrong. If however that works, one possible error source might be that your `printDialog1` object, which you seem to be instantiating outside the code section in question (maybe inside `InitializeComponent`), has somehow become invalidated.

Comment: Thanks. Adding a new instance fixed the problem. Now to diagnose what caused the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code you're hiding doesn't actually throw an exception (specifically the printing event for that dialog), this exception is usually because of apartment threading issues. You need to make the thread calling `Print()` be `STA`.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? There are currently no threads being created or used during the program.

Comment: **1.** (Preliminary:) Make sure you are running `printDialog1.ShowDialog()` on the same thread that created the thread. **2.** **a)** If that thread is the program's main thread, mark your program's entry point method (e.g. `Main`) with the `[STAThread]`attribute. **b)** If it's a thread you created yourself, use `thread.SetApartmentState(…)` before you `.Start()` the thread. **c)** If it's a thread pool thread, then you cannot use that thread for your purpose (because the thread pool uses only MTA threads). Resort to option b, i.e. create the print dialog on a thread you created yourself.

Comment: Thanks for that. It didn't work for this, but it did fix a problem I'd been having in a legacy system.

Comment: If this won't fix it, then I'm certain your event is throwing an exception. Enable Visual Studio to catch managed exceptions for your applications (CTRL-E-E and check all managed exceptions) and run it again, see what pops up. Also check inner exceptions!